# Traefik in AWS Elastik Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, traefik

Has anybody installed the traefik.io proxy in an Elastik Beanstalk environment and if so how?

I like EBS for its fail over capabilities and ease of maintenance so I'm thinking it would be a good platform to host traefik.

Traefik then would route traffic to other microservices that run in separate EBS environments. In particular I would like to use traefik for canary testing of new microservice versions.

Comment: Hi, I am also having a similar use case. Did you find any answer?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I also played around with Route53 traffic routing too, but the approach is not ideal as the dns refresh time interferes with the ability to accurately route a certain percentage of traffic. In the end I ran out of time and we ended up doing a cold switch over during go live without any canary approach.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I also spent some time on it and trying to move to AWS's load balancer.